# Agregar marcadores sin recargar mapa Android

Tags: android, google-maps, map

Buena tarde!! ya estuve googleando de saber si hay alguna forma de agregar un marcador a un mapa sin tener que volver a cargar onMapReady.

Esto es lo que intente:
Con el siguiente codigo ejecuto `Alerts` que es un WS que me esta regresando una serie de posiciones Lat/Long cada 5 segundos

```
   public void viewAlertas() {
    AppLog.Log("", "refresmap");

    scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Alerts();                    }

            });
        }


    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

al tener las posiciones las paso en una lista llamada coords y recorro esa lista para pintar el marker

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    map = googleMap;


    AppLog.Log("", "ResponseAlert2 :" + coords);

    for (int i = 0; i < coords.size(); i++) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(coords.get(i).latitude,coords.get(i).longitude))
                .title(mylistnombre.get(i))
                .snippet(myIdAlertWalker.get(i)));
        AppLog.Log("Marker", "Punto " + coords);

    }
    double latitudeInicial= Double.parseDouble(TrakingApplication.preferenceHelper.getLatWalker());
    double longitudeInicial= Double.parseDouble(TrakingApplication.preferenceHelper.getLonWalker());
    AppLog.Log("Marker","Punto "+ latitudeInicial + " " + longitudeInicial);

    // Cámara
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitudeInicial, longitudeInicial),13));

    // Eventos
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            TrakingApplication.preferenceHelper.putIdAlertWalker(marker.getSnippet());
           Intent intent =  new Intent(getActivity(), Polyline.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

cuando se pinta los marcadores por primera vez y a los 5 segundos que se vuelve a ejecutar `Alerts`se necesita hacer un refresh en el mapa, intente con

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Alguno tendra una idea de como se hace y me pudiera ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: Que as intentado hasta ahora ?

Comment: Ulises, has realizado anteriormente buenas preguntas, porque ahora preguntas sin agregar detalles?, te sugiero modificarla y tendrás buenas respuestas . Revisar [ask].

Comment: Ya actualice la información es que no encontraba la forma de explicarme!! espero sea de utilidad. muchas gracias!!